# Argument of type 'Barable' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'

Tags: typescript, generics, inheritance

Can someone explain, why this code doesn't work:

```
class Fooable {
    foo: string;
}
class Barable extends Fooable { 
    bar: boolean;
}

function simplifiedExample<T extends Fooable>(): Array<T> {
    let list = new Array<T>();
        list.push(new Barable());
    return list;
}
```

Barable is extending Fooable. Why I can't add Barable to a Array, when T must be Fooable?
Here code in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Fooable%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0Aclass%20Barable%20extends%20Fooable%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20simplifiedExample%3CT%20extends%20Fooable%3E()%3A%20Array%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20list%20%3D%20new%20Array%3CT%3E()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list.push(new%20Barable())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20list%3B%0A%7D)

**EDIT:**

the problem is, simplifiedExample() is an override from a base class, the base class is just a definition. Because is a mixed projekt JS/TS.

see:
[new playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Definition%20in%20a%20d.ts%0Adeclare%20class%20Fooable%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%2F%2F%20Definition%20in%20a%20d.ts%0Adeclare%20class%20FooableService%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20simplifiedExample%3CT%20extends%20Fooable%3E()%3A%20Array%3CT%3E%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Extendig...%0Aclass%20Barable%20extends%20Fooable%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%7D%0Aclass%20BarableService%20extends%20FooableService%20%7B%20%0A%0A%20%20%20%20simplifiedExample%3CT%20extends%20Fooable%3E()%3A%20Array%3CT%3E%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20list%20%3D%20new%20Array%3CFooable%3E()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list.push(new%20Barable())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20list%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

I found a solution with a cast, but it does not seem like a proper solution to me:

```
class BarableService extends FooableService { 

    simplifiedExample<T extends Fooable>(): Array<T> { 
        let list = new Array<Fooable>();
            list.push(new Barable());
        return list as Array<T>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the type `T` is compatible with `Fooable` and the type `Barable` is compatible with `Fooable`, that doesn't mean `Barable` is compatible with `T`.

For example:

```
class Bazable extends Fooable {
    baz: number;
}

const result: Bazable[] = simplifiedExample<Bazable>();
```

This reminds me a little of philosophy as you can see this is a non sequitur:

```
If T (Bazable) is a Fooable
And Barable is a Fooable
Then T (Bazable) is a Barable
```

Or...

```
If T (Lion) is a Cat
And Tiger is a cat
Then T (Lion) is a Tiger

     Cat
     / \
    /   \
Lion != Tiger
```

## Generic vs Structural

There are a number of cases in TypeScript that can be solved without generics, thanks to the structural type system. You may find that being honest about your `Barable` will work out just fine:

```
function simplifiedExample(): Barable[] {
    let list: Barable[] = [];
    list.push(new Barable());
    return list;
}
```

You don't need anything except a compatible structure for this to pass type checking:

```
class Bazable {
    foo: string;
    bar: boolean;
}

const a: Bazable[] = simplifiedExample();
```

Or even:

```
class Bazable {
    bar: boolean;
}

const a: Bazable[] = simplifiedExample();
```

And of course:

```
const a: Fooable[] = simplifiedExample();
```

If this doesn't suit your requirements, you may need to supply an example of where you think you need to introduce a generic type. Usually this would be if you wanted to construct a new `T` within the function, rather than a fixed type.

Comment: ok, thx. generics in TS don't work like in C#. but what's about this example:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Fooable%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0Aclass%20Barable%20extends%20Fooable%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20simplifiedExample%3CT%20extends%20Fooable%3E()%3A%20Array%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20list%20%3D%20new%20Array%3CFooable%3E()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list.push(new%20Barable())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20list%3B%0A%7D

Comment: @razgoolyy can you see if my update about leaning on structural typing may work - rather than generics - works in your case?

Comment: thx again for your help. I understand your suggestion. but i can not change the signature of the method. pls see the update of my post

Answer (score 0):

The type of your array list is known, it should be `Fooable`, hence the return type, as consequence.

Comment: this dosn't work too. [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Fooable%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0Aclass%20Barable%20extends%20Fooable%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20simplifiedExample%3CT%20extends%20Fooable%3E()%3A%20Array%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20list%20%3D%20new%20Array%3CFooable%3E()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list.push(new%20Barable())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20list%3B%0A%7D)

Comment: You should also change the return type to array of `Fooable` as written in the answer.

Comment: i can not change the signature of the method. pls see the update of my post

Answer (score 0):

As @Fenton points out the compatibility of `T` and `Barable` cannot be checked in the function. If you need to create a new instance of `T` you can pass in the constructor:

```
function simplifiedExample<T extends Fooable>(ctor: new ()=> T): Array<T> {
    let list = new Array<T>();
        list.push(new ctor());
    return list;
}

const result1: Bazable[] = simplifiedExample(Bazable);
const result2: Barable[] = simplifiedExample(Barable);
```